# Toggling class doesn't trigger transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to trigger a transition by toggling a class. The class toggles and applies it's style to the element, but the transition does not trigger. The transition applies to all properties, so I don't think that that is the problem.

```js
function expandFunction(element) {
  element.classList.toggle("setHeightStyle");
}
```

```css
.setHeightStyle {
  height: 60px;
}

#expSect1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="setHeightStyle" id="expSect1" onclick="expandFunction(this)">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <br>
  <p>Content!<br>More content!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You should also change it to `onclick="expandFunction(this)"` and pass in the element.  There isn't much logic in giving it the id to look up the element, when you could just give it the element.

Comment: In what way is it not valid? Will implement second comment.

Comment: Giving it the id, to look up the element, is not invalid.  It is inefficient and unnecessary.  My first comment stated why.

Comment: Got it. I changed it, but still nothing happened.

Comment: The commas in `<div class="setHeightStyle" , id="expSect1" , onclick="expandFunction(id)">` are invalid HTML. They're ignored, but still invalid.

Comment: Okay, I updated it.

Comment: You have to add `animation: height 1s linear` somewhere

Comment: Are you trying to transition the height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only the comas in the HTML need to be fixed.

You need to specify the property on which the `transition` wil apply... If not sure, use `all`.

For the transition to take effect, the `height` has to be defined in the `#expSect1` rule... Because the transition need a numeric value to start with. `auto` does not work.

Additionally, an `id` is more specific than a class... So you need to use both the class and the `id` on the rule to be toggled.

See the below working snippet.

```js
function expandFunction(elementID) {
  let element = document.getElementById(elementID);
  element.classList.toggle("setHeightStyle");
}
```

```css
#expSect1.setHeightStyle {
  height: 60px;
}

#expSect1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 200px;
  transition: all 1s;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="setHeightStyle" id="expSect1" onclick="expandFunction(id)">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <br>
  <p>Content!<br>More content!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the height is not initially set on the element. I had to change the selector for the added class html because of your selector specificity with the id. In general, do not use IDs for styling. Only use them for javascript.

```js
function expandFunction(element) {
  element.classList.toggle("setHeightStyle");
}
```

```css
#expSect1 {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 1s;
}

#expSect1.setHeightStyle {
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="setHeightStyle" id="expSect1" onclick="expandFunction(this)">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <br>
  <p>Content!<br>More content!</p>
</div>
```